# New to Linux, I'm getting this recurring error "ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1 " please advise

Tags: grub2, 20.04

I get this error when trying to update my system, all appears to be functioning, but I am new to Linux so I may be missing something

```
ben@ben-laptop:~$ sudo apt -y upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_k3262n"
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic (5.4.0-40.44) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic (5.4.0-40.44) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda2
I: (UUID=a9642385-eacc-4155-b29f-90ba3692f639)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_0qqeus'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic package post-installation script s
ubprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-40-generic
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

> If I run update-grub by itself I get
>
> ```
> ben@ben-laptop:~$ sudo update-grub [sudo] password for
> ben:  /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of
> `bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_0qqeus'.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the exact same issue with Kubuntu 20.04.  **The problem is that the `/boot` partition has run out of spare space to update the kernel properly**. Hence it repeatedly fails on each retry (i.e. `sudo apt upgrade`).   You can check this by running `df-H` and if the Avail space is low (say under 100MB) for the `/boot` mount then you may run into the issue you are seeing.  First try `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove` then `sudo apt upgrade` to see if it automatically clears up space to fix the error. If not, see my solution below.

To fix it you need to **free up the space on your `/boot`**. How I did it:

1. Run `sudo dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers'` to give you a list of installed kernels and kernel-headers in your `/boot`.
2. Now you need to uninstall all of the ones you dont want **EXCEPT the current kernel** (find out current kernel by running `uname -r`). You probably should **KEEP any kernel newer** than the current kernel too.
3. Uninstall each kernel and kernel-header you dont want using:

   ```
   sudo apt purge {kernel-package-name}
   ```

   For example I ran:

   ```
   sudo apt purge linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
   ...
   sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic
   ...
   sudo apt purge linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
   ...
   sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic
   ...
   And so on...
   ```
4. Once you have removed enough kernels to free up space, restart your PC then try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` again and see if it succeeds and the error message goes away.

In future when it fills up again you may have to repeat this. I always thought the old kernels should get removed automatically or by using `sudo apt clean` and/or `sudo apt autoremove` but it seems not the case on some installs.

**If anyone knows how to auto-remove old kernels please share**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I gave up on it and installed Mint instead, as a new linux user it was beyond my knowledge base. Mint seemed to install fine, I'm not sure why Ubuntu didn't, I left it to sort its own drive allocation, surely it should allocate enough.

Comment: Here's my take on auto-removing kernels, on my website: https://wyphan.github.io/logfile/2020/12/17/kernel-snap-cleanup.html