# Expand /boot on ZFS in virtual machine

Tags: boot, partitioning, zfs

So I set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and because I wanted to try it out, I set it up to use ZFS. I use a disk size of 10GB and the installer decided to set up my bpool to have a capacity of 480M. However `df -h` shows

```
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_cub7km                          118M   92M   26M  78% /boot
```

I have 0 experience with ZFS and don't know what this is all about. I didn't even get one kernel update in without an error that initramfs couldn't write to the disk.

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=ff3fca52-c9f0-4369-9aaf-598aa999db8b)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

How can I expand that partition? Normally I'd just run gparted and move the sizes about a little, but zfs is supposed to be all advanced and stuff. I tried enabling autoexpand for bpool, but the issue persisted. I don't know where the remaining ~400MB space for that pool went either.

As a workaround I moved the initfs image file to my home directory and ran `apt upgrade` again, which did generate the new initramfs file without issue. But that seems dangerous and unnecessary.

*Edit*

I have reinstalled the virtual machine to use a traditional ext4 file system. Thus I can not try out any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207958/error-24-write-error-cannot-write-compressed-block)

Comment: It seems you had the same issue like here. Check this solution too, maybe it helps. It solved my problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293685/out-of-space-on-boot-zpool-and-cant-run-updates-anymore

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out of space on boot zpool and cant run updates anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293685/out-of-space-on-boot-zpool-and-cant-run-updates-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a "similar" error after install a few packages, similar as I am not running ZFS, but same error message.  I search and found your issue. Here is my error (see below).  I was able to get fix by following answer here, [New to Linux, I'm getting this recurring error "ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1 " please advise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256570/new-to-linux-im-getting-this-recurring-error-error-update-grub-returned-an)

TLDR; /boot was 100% full, cleaned out with `sudo apt clean;sudo apt auto-remove`, update-initramfs was run as part of `sudo apt auto-remove`, and was successful.

> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnotify-dev
> libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done libgtk2.0-0
> is already the newest version (2.24.32-4ubuntu4). libnotify-dev is
> already the newest version (0.7.9-1ubuntu2). libxss1 is already the
> newest version (1:1.2.3-1). libgconf-2-4 is already the newest version
> (3.2.6-6ubuntu1). libgtk-3-0 is already the newest version
> (3.24.20-0ubuntu1). libnss3 is already the newest version
> (2:3.49.1-1ubuntu1.2). The following packages were automatically
> installed and are no longer required:   libllvm9
> linux-headers-5.4.0-29 linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic
> linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic
> linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to
> remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
> upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B
> of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
> Y Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ... update-initramfs:
> deferring update (trigger activated) Processing triggers for
> initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.2) ... update-initramfs: Generating
> /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic Error 24 : Write error : cannot
> write compressed block  E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
> update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic with 1.
> dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
> installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:
> initramfs-tools E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
> (1)