# Out of space on boot zpool and cant run updates anymore

Tags: apt, initramfs, zfs, 20.10

I recently wiped my box and installed 20.10 which i love and is amazing! This time i decided i wanted to live on the edge and use the experimental zfs support but after some time installing packages and updates I now have a weird problem with my boot zpool being too full.

Anytime I hit "update now" in the software updater i get a message like this one:

```
The upgrade needs a total of 254 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 194 M of disk space on '/boot'. You can remove old kernels using 'sudo apt autoremove', and you could also set COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to reduce the size of your initramfs.
```

Ive run `sudo apt autoremove` and it removes nothing, i hesitate changing the compression on my initramfs because that more feels like a patch to a possible lower problem (maybe im wrong haha).

I can still manually upgrade with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but i get this error every time:

```
ERROR couldn't save system state: Minimum free space to take a snapshot and preserve ZFS performance is 20%.
```

When i run `zpool list` i get:

```
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool  1.88G  1.69G   185M        -         -    47%    90%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
rpool   460G   165G   295G        -         -    10%    35%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

so im at 90% capacity on my boot pool...

ive also tried `zsysctl service gc -a` to remove snap shots but that didnt seem to change the bpool usage...

So maybe i need to change my bpool allocated size? How do i do that?

Im also getting some weird initramfs failures when i upgrade/install but im not sure if thats related?

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-firmware (1.190.1+system76~1605123765~20.10~3894207) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-29-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=05a735a7-9e82-494e-be9b-171b1c132af5)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-29-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.137ubuntu12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-29-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=05a735a7-9e82-494e-be9b-171b1c132af5)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-29-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 initramfs-tools
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

running `zfs list -t snapshot` shows a bunch of snapshots for bpool:

```
NAME                                                                                                   USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_z4aetj                                                                72K      -      237M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_mtxh3h                                                                72K      -      237M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_72y92u                                                               105M      -      357M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_lo8d22                                                              85.2M      -      337M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_y7ihca                                                               104M      -      336M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_qs6vz5                                                              85.2M      -      318M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_cyg6vx                                                                72K      -      337M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_r6e64v                                                                56K      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_nrhjqi                                                                56K      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_kgfl6b                                                               104M      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_nw3nk0                                                              85.1M      -      199M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_m1b6l9                                                               104M      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_hnt98o                                                              85.1M      -      199M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_rj8ttq                                                                64K      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_da1f4s                                                                 0B      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_ljdo3n                                                                 0B      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_danwfz                                                                 0B      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_4sjbka                                                               104M      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_gl3ru4                                                                 0B      -      218M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_tdbgin                                                                 0B      -      218M  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_z4aetj                                                              71.7M      -     5.10G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_mtxh3h                                                               217M      -     5.25G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_72y92u                                                              33.3M      -     5.43G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_lo8d22                                                              30.2M      -     5.30G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_y7ihca                                                               224M      -     5.42G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_qs6vz5                                                              27.8M      -     5.23G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_cyg6vx                                                              56.3M      -     5.51G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_r6e64v                                                              56.6M      -     5.29G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_nrhjqi                                                              30.6M      -     5.29G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_kgfl6b                                                              7.01M      -     5.25G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_nw3nk0                                                              29.6M      -     5.17G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_m1b6l9                                                               222M      -     5.32G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_hnt98o                                                              27.7M      -     5.13G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_rj8ttq                                                              26.2M      -     5.17G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_da1f4s                                                               155M      -     5.29G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_ljdo3n                                                              24.9M      -     5.61G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_danwfz                                                               181M      -     5.74G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_4sjbka                                                               498M      -     5.66G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_gl3ru4                                                                 0B      -     5.92G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_fjp6bn@autozsys_tdbgin                                                                 0B      -     5.92G  -
```

But im not firmilar enough with zfs or zsys to know if i can just destroy snapshots?

Comment: try `sudo apt --purge autoremove `

Comment: Ran that and it didnt change anything :(

Comment: Check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels - I assumed it was setup to do its thing, automatically - perhaps isn't.

Comment: Hmm... reading through that; it holds a lot about 14.04 - maybe avoid the very last things there (the "manual" stuff)

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-18-04-remove-all-unused-old-kernels/ - looks better IMO.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i think i fixed it...
I ran `zfs list -t snapshot | grep bpool` to list of all the snapshots for the boot pool. Then `sudo zfs destroy bpool/...` for a handful of snapshots starting from the top of the list until `zpool list` showed bpool at around 60% CAP. Then ran `sudo apt upgrade` and it ran mkinitramfs successfully! And now my bpool is around 70% :shrug:

Comment: How remove only large snapshots?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is snapshots in `bpool`. Simply removing them creates new problems because every zpool on the system has an identically named snapshot and `update-grub` and `update-initramfs` rely on that fact. If you only remove `bpool` snapshots both commands take a really long time and it's annoying. The only way I found to fix it was to delete **all** of the snapshots. Here's the command I used:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -r  | grep auto | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 sudo zfs destroy
```

Unfortunately, this kills any snapshots so you won't have the benefit of being able to revert your system to a previous time. There's got to be a way to expand the size of `bpool`!

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Freed 90% of space on /boot... It was __somewhat__ clogged.

Comment: Why does the default ZFS-Install of Ubuntu still create such a ridiculously small  `/boot`-Partition? This runs full sooner or later on every installation. It just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Attempting to clear space on /boot/**

`uname -r` tells which kernel you're running; this version cannot be removed.

Simple list:
`dpkg --list | grep linux-` will show kernel-related stuff, among other items.

Advanced, list installed (ii in leftmost column) items that MIGHT be purged:
`dpkg --list | grep -E '^ii.*linux-(headers|image|modules)' | grep -v $(uname -r)`

Now check which items (`_name_`) you CAN remove, and do
`sudo apt purge _name_`
... on them.

Comment: hmm interesting! so running uname shows me `5.8.0-29-generic` and running the simple list command gives me a whole list of different kernels i have (25, 28 and 29) and it seems like that last command shows still a bunch of things related to 5.8.0-29 ? linux-headers and such?

Comment: but i guess the 29 stuff is not `-generic`? so its ok to remove?

Comment: Avoid removing the latest version of those, assuming that is the version you're using. Read the middle column thoroughly. Don't touch 'hwe' -items. I realized that `uname -r` does not include the last `.digit`.