# Why is initramfs-tools stopping an upgrade?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, initramfs

Spare me as this is the first question I ever post in here.

So I tried to update on Ubuntu 22.04 using the command line and everything was fine until I got the error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Here:

> Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-27-lowlatency
> I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda1
> I: (UUID=d0783d7d-a3db-4dbb-a784-8b92c1aa4355)
> I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
> zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed
> block)
> E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 25
> update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-27-lowlatency with 1.
> dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
> installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned
> error exit status 1
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> initramfs-tools
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  <

So, I really have no what is going on. The boot partition still has space in it and as far as I can see I can't install anything after I sudo apt update and then tried the sudo apt upgrade.

It is only recently that I started using Linux and just began using Lubuntu 22.04.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok so, I purged initramfs-tools

Everything is "fine"

I guess I'm going to find out what happens next when I turn the laptop off and then turn it back on.

Oh boy, I really do like Linux but...

Comment: Your output says `Write error : No space left on device`. Did you investigate that?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293685/out-of-space-on-boot-zpool-and-cant-run-updates-anymore

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case your `/boot` directory doesn't have enough space, although not full, because of old kernels. Please, try deleting old packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

I had this problem and it solved for me. [This thread on the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471964) dealt with a similar issue, if not the same.

Comment: This was the case for me after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS: Although I only had 2 kernels there, the `/boot` partition was quite small, so not enough for 3 kernels (on my system 22.04LTS has significantly larger `initrd` files). Running `apt upgrade` or `apt-get upgrade` when the `initrd` file needed to be rebuilt (from earlier failed runs) was trying to create - temporarily - an additional `initrd` file which would later replace one of the existing `initrd` files. My quick fix was to move the not-in-use `initrd` file to (say) `/root`, perform the upgrade, then move it back.

Answer (score 1):

After an `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, I had possible missing firmware issues, so I followed this [guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu).

Then I ran into this error:

> ubuntu pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package:
> installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 1 (313)

So I did the following, thanks to both @lucasresck and @Ciro Santilli's, as their answers helped.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

and

```
zfs list -t snapshot -r  | grep auto | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 sudo zfs destroy
```

Then, I continued with the guide, and my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The magic command is:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -r  | grep auto | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs -n 1 sudo zfs destroy
```

from [Out of space on boot zpool and cant run updates anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293685/out-of-space-on-boot-zpool-and-cant-run-updates-anymore/1374204#1374204) Ubuntu REALLY needs to fix this stuff.