# Not enough free disk space on /boot kernels not there to be removed?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I've tried many of the answers I could find repeatedly. They all result in the same error. I'm not sure the cause, but the state feels like it's still half way between upgrading from 6.2.0-26 to 6.2.0-27. But that's totally conjecture on my side. I can't figure why it's in this state, and every document I've tried to follow to purge old kernels fails because it seems like while the old kernels are visible they are not installed?

I tried following the suggestion in the software updater, by changing the COMPRESS=xz in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf but that also difference in the available space.

```
> sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Requesting to save current system state
ERROR couldn't save system state: Minimum free space to take a snapshot and preserve ZFS performance is 20%.
Free space on pool "bpool" is 9%.
Please remove some states manually to free up space. 
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (6.2.0-27.28) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.2.0-27-generic
Setting up linux-firmware (20230323.gitbcdcfbcf-0ubuntu1.5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=9707427f-ea21-4f24-a222-71616b39623d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
xz: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure xz  --check=crc32 --threads=0 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 6.2.0.27.27); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the err
or message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                  Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu2) ...
ln: failed to create hard link '/boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
cp: cannot create regular file '/boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (6.2.0-27.28) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-27-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-27-generic
touch: cannot touch '/boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-27-generic.new': No space left on device
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=9707427f-ea21-4f24-a222-71616b39623d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
xz: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure xz  --check=crc32 --threads=0 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-27-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (6.2.0-26.26) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-26-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
I: (UUID=9707427f-ea21-4f24-a222-71616b39623d)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
xz: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure xz  --check=crc32 --threads=0 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Disk use:

```
> df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                             3.2G  2.9M  3.2G   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j                          794G  7.9G  786G   1% /
tmpfs                                              16G   97M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             5.0M   16K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
rpool/USERDATA/matt_7cxeqg                        846G   61G  786G   8% /home/matt
rpool/USERDATA/root_7cxeqg                        786G  1.2M  786G   1% /root
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/srv                      786G  128K  786G   1% /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/usr/local                786G  177M  786G   1% /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/lib                  795G  9.1G  786G   2% /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/games                786G  128K  786G   1% /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/snap                 786G  2.4M  786G   1% /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/log                  787G  766M  786G   1% /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/mail                 786G  128K  786G   1% /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/www                  786G  128K  786G   1% /var/www
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/spool                786G  128K  786G   1% /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/lib/AccountsService  786G  128K  786G   1% /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/lib/NetworkManager   786G  256K  786G   1% /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/lib/apt              786G   97M  786G   1% /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zwy26j/var/lib/dpkg             786G   50M  786G   1% /var/lib/dpkg
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_zwy26j                          288M  258M   30M  90% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                    511M   72M  440M  14% /boot/efi
tmpfs                                             3.2G  128K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Kernel images

```
> dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image'                                                                     
ic  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic              5.13.0-40.45                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-27-generic              5.15.0-27.28                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic              5.15.0-30.31                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic              5.15.0-33.34                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-35-generic              5.15.0-35.36                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-37-generic              5.15.0-37.39                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-39-generic              5.15.0-39.42                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-40-generic              5.15.0-40.43                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic              5.15.0-41.44                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic              5.15.0-46.49                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic              5.15.0-47.51                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic              5.15.0-48.54                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic              5.15.0-52.58                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-23-generic              5.19.0-23.24                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic              5.19.0-26.27                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-28-generic              5.19.0-28.29                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-29-generic              5.19.0-29.30                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-31-generic              5.19.0-31.32                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic              5.19.0-35.36                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic              5.19.0-40.41                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic              5.19.0-41.42                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic               6.2.0-20.20                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.2.0-23-generic               6.2.0-23.23                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.2.0-24-generic               6.2.0-24.24                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-6.2.0-25-generic               6.2.0-25.25                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic               6.2.0-26.26                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic               6.2.0-27.28                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iU  linux-image-generic                        6.2.0.27.27                             amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Fail to remove old images that aren't there?

```
> sudo apt remove linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic                                                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
^C⏎
```

```
> uname -r
6.2.0-26-generic
```

```
ls -l /boot                                                                                                      
total 263675
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    275950 Jul 10 17:25 config-6.2.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    275939 Jul 12 18:22 config-6.2.0-27-generic
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 Dec 31  1969 efi/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      4096 Aug 16 10:05 grub/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 235906921 Aug 11 09:16 initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        27 Aug 11 09:16 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    138712 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+ia32.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    139776 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+ia32.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    144312 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+x64.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    145408 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+x64.efi
-rw------- 1 root root   8163538 Jul 10 17:25 System.map-6.2.0-26-generic
-rw------- 1 root root   8166850 Jul 12 18:22 System.map-6.2.0-27-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Aug 11 09:16 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-27-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  14482632 Jul 10 17:31 vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  13872968 Jul 12 18:23 vmlinuz-6.2.0-27-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        24 Aug 11 09:16 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic
```

As you can see by the directory listing. The boot space is used primarily by a single file which cannot be removed
initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic is using 225M of the 258M used in the /boot directory. I cannot remove the only active kernel so I cannot follow the steps in removing extra kernels. Please do not close this as duplicate.

The boot partition was created with default installation settings for Ubuntu. The updates were always applied from the software updater. The dpkg shows a bunch of kernels but using the remove command shows they aren't installed to be removed.

When I open the "Disks" application I can't even see the /boot partition. Only /boot/efi which still has plenty of space, as well as other unmounted partitions?

[image: gparted screenshot showing /boot/efi]

Comment: You're using ZFS, and it can't show you the zvols inside a zpool (and your `df` output clearly shows its a zvol). You can try resizing the zvol or cleaning up snapshots in it: https://askubuntu.com/q/1293685/158442 That said, `initrd.img-6.2.0-26-generic` can definitely be removed - your system is booted and already running, after all. (If you're nervous, move it elsewhere instead of removing it, but either way, it doesn't _have_ to be there.) Then you can finish the apt update and work on resizing your volumes.

Comment: Thank you, it was apparently never about my /boot partition being too full, despite the error. Clearing up a few snapshots from the bpool (which I have not seen referenced in any of the other /boot full issues) resolved it and I was able to complete the updates successfully.