# Error "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1

Tags: 21.10, error-handling, zfs

Everytime I want to install or remove some package via terminal with `sudo apt-get install ...` or `sudo apt-get remove ...`, I finally get the following error:

```
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1
```

With the guide on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256570/new-to-linux-im-getting-this-recurring-error-error-update-grub-returned-an) page I have some problems of understanding. E.g. with command

```
df -H
```

I get following table, and for me it seems to be enough available space:

```
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                             381M  2.2M  379M   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo                          292G  4.5G  287G   2% /
tmpfs                                             2.0G  689k  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
rpool/USERDATA/martin_rc5gt4                      291G  3.8G  287G   2% /home/martin
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/log                  287G   39M  287G   1% /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/www                  287G  132k  287G   1% /var/www
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/games                287G  132k  287G   1% /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/lib                  290G  2.8G  287G   1% /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/spool                287G  132k  287G   1% /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/lib/NetworkManager   287G  263k  287G   1% /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/mail                 287G  132k  287G   1% /var/mail
rpool/USERDATA/root_rc5gt4                        287G  263k  287G   1% /root
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/usr/local                287G  132k  287G   1% /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/snap                 287G  1.2M  287G   1% /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/lib/apt              287G   94M  287G   1% /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/lib/dpkg             287G   42M  287G   1% /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/srv                      287G  132k  287G   1% /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo/var/lib/AccountsService  287G  132k  287G   1% /var/lib/AccountsService
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_vp6vyo                          1.7G  164M  1.6G  10% /boot
/dev/sda2                                         537M   17M  521M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs                                             381M   31M  350M   9% /run/user/1000
```

Is their a way to solve this problem? I'm working on Ubuntu 21.10.

While installing Ubuntu 2 weeks ago I've choosen the following option. Cause with the option none after the installation the reboot dropped me into some console window and not into Ubuntu itself. Maybe their is some connection with that error message.

[image]

Comment: The command is `df -h`. The `-h` is for human readable. See [df manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/df.1.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grub-update` script is called by `apt` or `apt-get`, if an update or newly installed packages affects grub or boot loader related scripts.

Take a look into grub configuration in `/etc/grub.d/`

```bsh
$ ls -la /etc/grub.d/
total 148
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 24 08:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 154 root root 12288 Feb 11 11:22 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10627 Jan 13  2021 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6258 Jan 13  2021 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 18151 Aug 12  2021 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 42359 Jan 13  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12894 Jan 13  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Aug 18  2020 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12059 Jan 13  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1424 Jan 13  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Jan 13  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Jan 13  2021 41_custom
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Jan 13  2021 README
```

`grub-update` generates the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from these snippets. However, the `10_linux_zfs` might not be the cause of the error. So you need to check the generation process. Just run the following command.

```
$ bash -ex /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This generates a lot of output, but the last few messages should give you an indication, where the problem is located.